# Bootstrap form shifting to the top for no apparent reason

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 and the simplified code from below, I cannot figure out why the first form shifts a bit to the top compared to the other two forms in the row:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- our own css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" type="text/css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title></title>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div><h1><b>bohoo</b></h1></div>
        <br />
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class= "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 gray">
                    <h3>here's a title</h3>
                    <form action="." method="post">
                            {{numberform}}
                            <p> </p>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="x" value="A value">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="y" value="A value">
                    </form>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group move-right">
                <div class= "col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 gray">
                    <h3>here's a title</h3>
                    <form action="." method="post">
                            {{textform}}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="z" value="A value">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="y" value="A value">
                    </form>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group move-right">
                <div class= "col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 gray">
                    <h3>uuu a title</h3>
                    <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                       {{fileform}}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="a" value="A value">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="b" value="A value">
                    </form>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center">
                <hr>
                <h3><b>Result:</b></h3>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
                    {{result}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result in Chrome, tested on multiple screens and sizes:

[image: Form shifting to the top. Screenshot[1]]

And here is my `style.css`:

```
.gray {
background-color: #f2efef;
border-radius: 15px;
}

.move-right {
    padding-left: 200pt;
}
```

I cannot figure out what could cause the first form from the left to shit to the top a bit. I tried all sorts of gimmicks to fix this, but padding, adding a margin-top, and even adding `<br>`s did not help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form-group class is messing it up. You've wrapped all the 1/3 width div's with full width "form-group" div's.

Take the form-group classes off those div's and add the form-group class to it's child div. The div's with the col-md-3, etc. You could probably get rid of those wrapping div's entirely.

Comment: Also I am noticing something weird on the before psuedo element before your first form-group. Bootstrap appears to be inserting a blank string of content.

It starts on line 6461 and goes to line 6495 of boostrap.css .

Comment: In Bootstrap the `.row` parent's direct child should be `.col` otherwise you might run into some unwanted behavior https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95594/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that's happening but would this override work?

```css
.gray{
   margin-top:0px;
   }
```